# JBoss AS 7: Non-EJB dependency in another EAR

Tags: jboss7.x

I've got an EAR with the following structure:

```
ear.ear    
  mywar.war
    lib
      jar1.jar
      jar2.jar
      jar3.jar
```

I've got multiple WARs in the deployments directory and I'd like them to have jar1.jar. jar2.jar and jar3.jar from ear.ear as dependencies.

Is this possible?

I've tried the following for jboss-deployment-structure.xml with no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.ear.ear.jar1.jar"/>
            <module name="deployment.ear.ear.jar2.jar"/>
            <module name="deployment.ear.ear.jar3.jar"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
        <deployment>
            <dependencies>
                <module name="deployment.ear.ear.lib.jar1.jar"/>
                <module name="deployment.ear.ear.lib.jar2.jar"/>
                <module name="deployment.ear.ear.lib.jar3.jar"/>
            </dependencies>
        </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Is it possible to have non-ejb JAR dependencies in a separate EAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to place the dependencies in the `/lib` folder of your ear, and your wars should see them.

From the JBoss AS7 documentation:

> Ear deployments are multi-module deployments. This means that not all
>   classes inside an ear will necessarily have access to all other
>   classes in the ear, unless explicit dependencies have been defined. By
>   default the EAR/lib directory is a single module, and every WAR or EJB
>   jar deployment is also a separate module. Sub deployments (wars and
>   ejb-jars) always have a dependency on the parent module, which gives
>   them access to classes in EAR/lib, however they do not always have an
>   automatic dependency on each other

You can also read more about class loading in JBoss AS 7: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: The problem I have is I have WARs deployed outside of the EAR. It seems that these WARs can only have dependencies on EJB JARs inside this EAR.

I think the best way to approach my problem is to create a custom jboss module and put my dependencies in there.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Jar files in an ear are a deployed as a single module. You can indicate a dependency on these using `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` by specifying a dependency on the ear itself. You will also need to include any ejbs separately and include `export="TRUE"`.

For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- our module depends on the libs within myear.ear -->
            <module name="deployment.myear.ear" export="TRUE"/>
            <!-- and these ejbs -->
            <module name="deployment.myear.ear.ejb1.jar" export="TRUE"/>
            <module name="deployment.myear.ear.ejb2.jar" export="TRUE"/>
            <module name="deployment.myear.ear.ejb3.jar" export="TRUE"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```